# python struct.pack and write vs matlab fwrite

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, memory, struct

I am trying to port this bit of matlab code to python

**matlab**

```
function write_file(im,name)
 fp = fopen(name,'wb');

 M = size(im);

 fwrite(fp,[M(1) M(2) M(3)],'int');
 fwrite(fp,im(:),'float');

 fclose(fp);
```

where `im` is a 3D matrix. As far as I understand, the function first writes a binary file with a header row containing the matrix size. The header is made of 3 integers. Then, the `im` is written as a single column of floats. In matlab this takes few seconds for a file of 150MB.

**python**

```
import struct
import numpy as np
def write_image(im, file_name):

    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
       l = im.shape[0]*im.shape[1]*im.shape[2]

       header = np.array([im.shape[0], im.shape[1], im.shape[2]])
       header_bin = struct.pack("I"*3, *header)
       f.write(header_bin)

       im_bin = struct.pack("f"*l,*np.reshape(im, (l,1), order='F'))
       f.write(im_bin)
    f.close()
```

where `im` is a numpy array. This code works well as I compared with the binary returned by matlab and they are the same. However, for the 150MB file, it takes several seconds and tends to drain all the memory (in the image linked I stopped the execution to avoid it, but you can see how it builds up!).

[image: see memory usage]

This does not make sense to me as I am running the function on a 15GB of RAM PC. How come a 150MB file processing requires so much memory?

I'd happy to use a different method, as far as it is possible to have two formats for the header and the data column.

Comment: No need for product: `l = im.size`

Comment: What is `header`?

Comment: Also, yeah, you created a string the same size as the entire image, then copied the entire image itself. Yeah, that's going to suck you dry alright.

Comment: Thanks for the update. `np.array([im.shape[0], im.shape[1], im.shape[2]])` -> `np.array(im.shape)`

Comment: fixed, `header` is an array with `im.shape` inside

Comment: Your text says four integers in the header, but you are only writing 3 in both cases. Are you missing something or is the 4 a typo?

Comment: I have not tested my answer so I will help you work out any issues you encounter as you try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use `struct` to save your array. `numpy.ndarray` has a convenience method for saving itself in binary mode: [`ndarray.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile). The following should be much more efficient than creating a gigantic string with the same number of elements as your array:

```
def write_image(im, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
        np.array(im.shape).tofile(f)
        im.T.tofile(f)
```

`tofile` always saves in row-major C order, while MATLAB uses column-major Fortran order. The simplest way to get around this is to save the transpose of the array. In general, `ndarray.T` should create a view (wrapper object pointing to the same underlying data) instead of a copy, so your memory usage should not increase noticeably from this operation.

Comment: definitely doing the trick! thank you

I just modified the last line as

`im.astype('f').T.tofile(f)`
so that the array is in float32